# Append different values to even and odd lines in a list

Tags: bash, vim, sed

I need to append the following list:

```
urack-L-
urack-L-
urack-L-
urack-L-
urack-L-
```

with urack-L-

```
urack-L-100
urack-L-101
urack-L-100
urack-L-101
urack-L-100
```

and so on...

I haven't been able to find a method other than incremental (100,101,102, etc...)  Any short and sweet sed tricks?

Comment: This was supposed to paste as a column, sorry.

Comment: You have to indent with four spaces for text to be printed verbatim (i.e., not have linebreaks removed).

Comment: Does it alternate between 100 and 101 like your example, or increment from 100 like your text indicates?

Comment: Related post: [In Vim how can I search and replace every other match?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13763880/438329)

Answer (score 4):

awk:

```
awk '{printf "%s%d\n", $0, 101 - NR % 2}' file
```

The `NR` variable holds the current record number, by default the current line number. `NR % 2` evaluates to 0 or 1 for even or odd numbered lines.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @Alexander you are completely wrong. Please don't clutter up the site commenting on posts you don't understand. Thanks.

Comment: Ed, that's what comments are for, too ask questions about stuff that's hard to understand

Comment: Yeah I know but I also know that this guy has zero interest in the question or your answer and only posted his comment because some automated tool flagged your answer as possibly low quality since it was just code, and so he rubber-stamped it without having any clue if it was really low quality or not. Code only does not equal low quality, the tool is simply asking **people who know the domain** to make a determination, and tiny trivial scripts are best left for people to look up the man page to explain if they don't understand them.

Answer (score 2):

If you have GNU sed, you can use an extension to addresses:

```
sed '1~2s/$/100/;2~2s/$/101/' infile
```

where the address `first~step` matches the line with address *`first`* and then every *`step`*th line.

Or, as pointed out in ctac's comment:

```
sed 's/$/100/;n;s/$/101/' infile
```

This uses the `n` command to print the pattern space (containing an odd line) and loading the next (even) line into it. This should work with any POSIX-conformant sed.

Comment: With all sed: sed 's/$/100/;n;s/$/101/' infile

Answer (score 1):

```
 :%s/$/\=(line(".")%2==0?"101":"100")/


 % ................ whole file
 s ................ substitute 
 $ ................ end of line
 \=(line(".") ..... gets the number of the current line
 %2==0? ........... if the rest of division equals zero
```

Reference [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10414708/2571881).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't appropriate for `sed`. Just use a shell loop with a variable that you test.

```
i=100
while read line
do
    echo "$line$i"
    if [[ i == 100 ]]
    then i=101
    else i=100
    fi
done < inputfile > outputfile
```

Comment: Shorter: `i=$(( i == 100 ? 101 : 100 ))`

Comment: Shorter still `i=10$((++i%2))` but in any case see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for some of the issues with this and do it with the right tool for the job, awk (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50769618/1745001).

Answer (score 0):

Also a regex could work fine:

```
:%s/\(^.*\)\n\(.*\)/\1100\r\2101/g
```